# How to pick specific city through data in google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to pick data of a specific city, there are 6 different city name in Col D in the file. Entire data picking script is working fine but need the code to pick only one city data out of 6 different cities. What will be the script. The current script is as below.

```
function kws_carpenter(ssA, ssB) {

var main_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1P0MQ4IQ0r_WE2yQT6W-jK04yCUR_QpO3t3LHZnM2uGc");
var main_tab = main_sheet.getSheetByName('Data');
main_tab.getRange('A1:P48633').clearContent();
  
 // source sheet
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Lvw-0Ql9ImXq6sVda7h8cSBg7U_R8HIpWeJnuC8dRsk");
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Dump');
  var SRange = ss.getRange("A2:P48634");
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
 var SData = SRange.getDisplayValues();
 
 // target spreadsheet
 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openByenter code hereId("1P0MQ4IQ0r_WE2yQT6W-jK04yCUR_QpO3t3LHZnM2uGc");
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('data'); enter code here
   ts.getRange("A1:P48633").setValues(SData);
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The code doesn't look to be relevant for what it's being asked. Please show what you tried regarding what is being asked and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. When adding code it should be a [mcve].

Comment: Hi Ruben, I have a sheet which is containing data from A1 to AB67000 and in colD there are 6 different cities. Currently we are picking the city wise data through importrange from A1:P67000 only but since due to the data is heavy we have to break the importrage after some time.  Now i am trying to pick data through script but unable to pick city wise entire data from A1:P67000 for all cities is getting picked up from above script

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add all the relevant details to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample script as reference:

```
function picRowData(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("##SHEETID##");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  var range = "D2:D7"; //Range of the Column D that contains 6 different cities
  var targetCity = "Yellowknife"; //Sample target city
  for(row=2; row<= sheet.getRange(range).getValues().length; row++){ //Loop starts at row 2 of Column D
    if(sheet.getRange(row,4).getValue() == targetCity){ //Check each row of Column D (Col #4) that matches targetCity value
      Logger.log("Target City: "+targetCity+"\nFound \""+targetCity+"\""+" on cell D"+row); //Logs the cell location of the cell on Column D that matches the Target City
     //sheet.getRange(row,4).getValue() contains the matched city
    }
  }
}
```

**Sample Sheet:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]